# How do I plot on matlab with dates along the x-axis

Tags: matlab, date, plot

I have two vectors(?) of data - one being prices, and the other the dates that those prices occured, and I am trying to plot a scatter plot of the two.

My dates are of the format ddmmyyyy and I have tried using mat2str to convert the vector into strings, and then used

formatin='ddmmyyy';
datenum(MYDATA,formatin)

however it returns an error saying that datenum has failed.

EDIT

This is the example of my code
This is what I am trying to run, where AvivaDate is a vector of 1200x1 double. The problem seems to be that mat2str is not changing the vector into a string of numbers: e.g. I need it in {'12345','12345'} form but mat2str is changing it into a string of '[12345' 12345]', so not a list of separate strings if that makes sense

```
formatin = 'ddmmyyyy';   
DateAviva = mat2str(AvivaDate);   
datenum(DateAviva,formatin);   
hist(ReturnAviva,datenum(AvivaDate,formatin));  
datetick('x','keepticks','keeplimits');
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of your data and the code used so that we can replicate the issue?

Comment: @am304

This is what I am trying to run, where AvivaDate is a vector of 1200x1 double. The problem seems to be that mat2str is not changing the vector into a string of numbers: e.g. I need it in {'12345','12345'} form but mat2str is changing it into a string of '[12345' 12345]', so not a list of separate strings if that makes sense

formatin = 'ddmmyyyy'; <br
DateAviva = mat2str(AvivaDate);
datenum(DateAviva,formatin);
hist(ReturnAviva,datenum(AvivaDate,formatin));
datetick('x','keepticks','keeplimits');

Comment: sorry I can't work out how to put line breaks in - \br doesn't seem to work in comments

Comment: Can you edit the original question? It would be better to add there.

Comment: Edit your question, it'll be a lot easier than putting it in the comments

Comment: @am304 have done. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat2str` is not the function you want to convert between numbers and strings. `mat2str` has a very specific function (you see how it puts the [] around the output?). Use `num2str`, then convert it into a cell array:

```
S = num2str(AvivaDate); % should be 1200 x 8 char
C = mat2cell(S,ones(size(S,1),1)); % should be 1200 x 1 cell
dates = datenum(C,'ddmmyyyy'); % should be 1200 x 1 datenums
```

Although, depending where you're getting the information from in the first place, there may be a better way of reading the dates in from file, so you don't end up with a matrix of numbers where you want dates in the first place.

Comment: This seems like it is almost working. I'm getting 1200 x 8 char return for C though, not S. dates also only returns one value, though I am getting 1200 values returned for S

Comment: If I take out the middle mat2cell line this seems to work! I'm not sure I quite understand the function of this line

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the second line, no MATLAB on here. In my head you need a cell array for `datenum` but maybe it works fine on char arrays after all.